# Suppress Publisher has been verified dialog popup for power point addin

Tags: windows-installer, office-addins

I am installing PowerPoint add-in using a Wix installer. When I install with the default path then the "Publisher has been verified" popup does not display but when I change the installation path and try to install then "Publisher has been verified" popup display.
If I click on the "Don't Install" button then add-in is not installed and if I uninstall and install again then for that path it never displays "Publisher has been verified" popup.
So, how can I suppress this popup and install PowerPoint automatically?

Note: I have digital signed exe.

Dialog image:

[image: Publisher]

I have also tried with adding registry key with below reference:

https://www.itninja.com/question/is-it-possible-to-disable-are-you-sure-you-want-to-install-this-customization-window-in-excel-2010-for-the-first-time-a-user-uses-powerpivot-for-excel-plugin